# Google map API custom overlays containing markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Is there a way to create multiple custom overlays containing marker subgroups, so that filtering could be quicker?

I want to create a set of checkboxes and toggle corresponding overlays to hide/show marker groups.

Comment: [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer), [FusionTableLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DataLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#Data) may be an option.

But I'm not sure if it's really "quicker" (I'm not sure if the API internally uses a loop to show or hide features of the Layers), but at least you don't need to implement such a loop on your own when you use a Data-Layer...you simply hide or show a Layer and all features within the Layer will be displayed/removed